# Sound played through bluetooth headset while ringing? - android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to get a sound (namely a small wav file representing the persons name - not auto generated) to play over a bluetooth headset while the phone is ringing.  Essentially it would replace the default ring of the bluetooth device and replace it with the name of the caller!... well, anyway... it's not working.

I've been able to play the wav file directly on the headset within an activity, but when moved to the onReceive function of the broadcast receiver it fails to play the same sound over the headset while the cell phone is ringing...

I feel like I must be missing something.  Is there something I can do to revise this code?

Thanks in advance

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mContext = context;
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {
        System.out.println("Its Ringing");

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        am.setBluetoothScoOn(true); 
        am.startBluetoothSco();
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 

        try{
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = mContext.getAssets().openFd("my.wav");
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);

            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());

            player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            player.prepareAsync();

        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println(ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
        }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be preparing/setting up your media player before you receive the phone call because this can take some time. Also, remove am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);, you could replace it with am.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL); but it is probably not necessary because you should already be in that mode if your BT device is paired/setup.